# How to fetch jenkins log between two timestamp using groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, logparser

My jenkins log is too big and often consoleFull did not load it completely.
So using groovy script fetching logs between timestamp like below.

```
JOBNAME = 'My_Jenkins_job'
BUILDID = '34'
def start = 23
def end = 25
def time_prefix = '2021-11-30T08:'

for (job in Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class)) {
    if (job.name == JOBNAME) {
        for (build in job.builds) {
            if (build.id == BUILDID) {
                def lines = build.logFile.readLines()

                println '===================================================='
                println "Log summary between ${time_prefix}${start}..${end}"
                println '======================================================='
                for (int i in start..end) {
                    def logmsg = lines.findAll {
                        it.contains("${time_prefix}${i}")
                    }
                    logmsg.each {
                        println it
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But here I am using string and contains to parse the timings ,But if I can use datetime in range it will be good. How to convert the date time format in Jenkins to groovy and put it in a range.

I am trying to convert time and it fails.

```
String log_time="2021-12-01T09:19:54-07:00"
String timestamp = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm-ss':00'", log_time) 
println(timestamp)
```

If I can convert the jenkins timestamp and put it in range operator I can extract the log between timestamp. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

def log_time='2021-12-01T09:19:54-07:00'
def timestamp = LocalDateTime.parse(log_time, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"))  
println timestamp
```